# React: requesting and iterating through images in JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm completely new to React and have just started learning through the React Tutorial on Facebook. I'm trying to grab images from a JSON file and repeat them (like Angular's ng-repeat) as posts, exactly like Instagram. I originally had a working comments section, but now it broke because I started adding more code I thought would fix it. It's gotten so sloppy I don't know what to do anymore.

So from what I read, I'm supposed to make a GET request through 'componentDidMount'. I see sources using $getJSON, $.ajax, $.get and I get confused on which to use and how to approach it.

```
let PostImage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      postImage: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      var collection = result.data.children;
      this.setState({
        postImage: collection
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    images = this.state.postImage || [];
    return (
      <div>
        Images: {images.map(function(image){
          return <img src={image}/>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <PostImage source="https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

My React.render is currently on PostImage, but the component at the highest level is InstagramPost (see Plnker below). I tried switching it to InstagramPost but it broke, so I'm confused there as well. In my console, I'm also seeing that

```
$ is not defined
```

I've attached a Plnker for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/AYxUjameK6dAqCYUiwQT?p=info

If you could also help get my comments section to work, that'd be great too. Thanks in advance.

**edit:** forgot to include jQuery in Plnker.

Comment: The `$` is most likely [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). It has nothing to do with React. If you want to use jQuery, you need to include it. Have a look at https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using jQuery `$.get` therefore you have to include jQuery script

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

jQuery `$.get` return already as data therefore you don't need to do result.data again, if you are not familiar with jQuery `$.get` read [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Your final componentDidMount should look like this

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
    var collection = result;
    this.setState({
      postImage: collection
    });
  }.bind(this));
},
```

For CommentBox just pass data={data} in

Comment: Great, thanks! Picture loads now. But there images are currently being listed in one div. I was wondering if you knew how to separate each image in their own div.... in their own "InstagramPost" component?

Comment: One way to do is to move images.map() to be in InstagramPost class instead. Just make sure to wrap everything up to be on node (div, span, etc)